# Pub/Sub ordering guarantees

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

I am going to use Pub/Sub platform for rtdn processing. I am a bit confused of some guarantees (if they exist, it will make my tasks much easier) of Pub/Sub platform, so I want to ask:

1. is it possible for message with less publishTime (for eg. publishTime = 12:00, found in request = 12:02) appear later, than one with bigger publishTime (publishTime = 12:01, found in request = 12:01)?
2. [wrong for sure if (1) is possible] are messages ordered by publishTime in [api request](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions/pull)? Is it guranteed if I'll request 2 batches (with aknowleding of all subs), that for every message1 from first batch and any message2 from second one `message1.publishTime <= message2.publishTime` will be true?

UPD: Okay, my question is a bit specific, I want to ask more general one also: Is there any attribute which can be used like offset in Apache Kafka? I'd like to have logic in my application with messages offsets and have ability to commit them sequentially (to be sure at every moment, that for commited offset every offset, which is less than commited, is processed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pub/Sub's ordering guarantees aren't based exactly on timestamp; they are based on "the order in which the servers received the requests." What that means is that in general, yes, messages will be delivered in timestamp order per ordering key. However, there is technically the possibility that a message received by the server later could be considered published at a timestamp earlier than a message that was received earlier, though in practice, it is extremely unlikely.

Therefore, messages returned in a response to the client will be sent in the order in which they were received. In general, yes, the timestamps will be increasing. Though keep in mind that given that Pub/Sub offers at-least-once delivery, it is possible for messages to get redelivered and those messages could have timestamps that are earlier than timestamps of messages already sent.

In general, it's best not to think in terms of offset and commit if using Cloud Pub/Sub's ordering feature (or Pub/Sub in general). Pub/Sub expects messages to be acknowledged individually. When using ordered delivery, acks for later messages are not processed until acks for earlier messages have been. What that means is that if you have messages 1, 2, and 3 with the same ordering key and you receive them all and ack only message 3, the service will not consider message 3 acked until messages 1 and 2 are acked. If acks for 1 and 2 are never received, then messages 1, 2, and 3 will be redelivered.